# Help identifying a black and white 1 x 1 LEGO part with clip on top

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

The numbers inside this brick are 01 B02.  The brick is a 1 x 1 black plate with a white clip inserted into a hole.  I have searched BrickLink with no success. I have also searched Google.  Hoping someone from here can help.

[image: Image of brick]

[image: Image of numbers]

Answer (score 6):

[image]
[image]

Hey there *Treppy*!

This is *[Part #93062c01 Leg Skeleton with Black Square Foot](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93062c01&idColor=1#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

Ya see, even the Skeletons know stepping on a *LEGO* bare boned is a no no!

See ya!